# retrieving data from firebase in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an angular module where I need to filter particular property of the data from firebase and store it in an array so that I can loop through it in my HTML.
**This is my component.ts file**

```
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { AngularFireDatabase, } from '@angular/fire/database';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { ImageService } from '../../image.service'
import { AngularFireStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-mobile',
  templateUrl: './mobile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mobile.component.css']
})
export class MobileComponent implements OnInit {
  images: any;
  name: string;
  type: any; 
  filters = {};
  nature :String;
  value:string;
  pictures:string[];

  constructor(private storage: AngularFireStorage,
              private db: AngularFireDatabase) {}

  ngOnInit() {    
     this.db.list('/images').valueChanges()
     .subscribe(images =>{
          this.images = images;
     })    
  }

 cato() {
    var ref = firebase.database().ref("/images");
    ref.orderByChild("name").equalTo("nature").once("child_added")
        .then(function(snapshot) {
          snapshot.forEach(item => console.log(item.val().picture))
          return this.item.val();
        });
      }
}
```

I am trying to filter the data to get only picture property in the data. Now I want to access all the list of `picture` values so that I can store it in a variable and access it in my HTML file.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: which version of angular ? and AngularFireStorage ?

Comment: Does it print `something` to the console when you do `item.val().pictuer`?

Comment: No its giving me an error:core.js:4081 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No index defined for name
Error: No index defined for name

Comment: try with snapshotChanges()

Comment: "firebase": "^7.17.1" and angular : 10.0.1

Comment: did'nt get you..

Comment: I am getting the same error...

Comment: You'll need to define an index for `name` in your Firebase security rules. Search for that error message: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D+No+index+defined+for to find previous questions covering the same problem, and how to solve it.